# How to upgrade to php version 7 from php5.2 in Production server (Linux Debian wheezy) running in apche2 web server

Tags: linux, laravel, php-7

we want to upgrade our php version and laravel to php v7 and laravel v5.4  from php v5.2 ,and laravel 4.2 .I  already upgraded locally in windows 7  , Now I want to upgrade in production server (Linux Debian (wheezy ) , so anyone please guide me correct solution . i went through below links, and i am not able to understand which one is correct and  i would follow , i am new to Linux OS , please anyone give me proper guidance and solution.

Thanks 
Devidas Pawar

Comment: links which i gone through

Comment: https://shiji.info/blog/2016/en/99


https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-php-7-on-debian-linux-8-jessie-wheezy-using-apt-get/


https://www.colinodell.com/blog/2015-12/installing-php-7-0-0

https://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-debian-wheezy

Comment: You have to compile from source. Download source, extract, run `./configure` with the desired options (your existing `phpinfo()` will have the options you're currently using), then `make` , find 1000 errors, install missing packages based on those errors, `make` again until all packages are installed, then `sudo make install`. Expect it to take several hours.

Comment: This question is probably better suited at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: you can ask your hosting provider about same.